# Ffmpeg Python - Why "filter" makes the output muted?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

Normally my input has an audio. When I convert my input with following code, the output is muted.

```
ffmpeg.input("input.webm").filter("scale", force_original_aspect_ratio="decrease", force_divisible_by=2).output(("out.mp4"), vcodec="libx264", r=60, preset='fast').run()
```

`.filter()` function causes it and I don't know how to fix it. I want to use filter, but I want to keep the audio same also.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the filter to video (only), and pass the filtered video and the original audio as arguments to `output(...)`:

```python
import ffmpeg

v = ffmpeg.input("input.webm").video.filter("scale", force_original_aspect_ratio="decrease", force_divisible_by=2)
a = ffmpeg.input("input.webm").audio
ffmpeg.output(v, a, "out.mp4", vcodec="libx264", r=60, preset='fast', acodec='aac').overwrite_output().run()
```

---

In case you want it in one line:
`ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input("input.webm").video.filter("scale", force_original_aspect_ratio="decrease", force_divisible_by=2), ffmpeg.input("input.webm").audio, "out.mp4", vcodec="libx264", r=60, preset='fast', acodec='aac').overwrite_output().run()`

---

For getting the equivalent command line, you may add `-report` global argument, and check the log file:

`ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input("input.webm").video.filter("scale", force_original_aspect_ratio="decrease", force_divisible_by=2), ffmpeg.input("input.webm").audio, "out.mp4", vcodec="libx264", r=60, preset='fast', acodec='aac').global_args('-report').overwrite_output().run()`

According to the log file, the equivalent command line is:

`ffmpeg -i input.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=force_divisible_by=2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[s0]" -map "[s0]" -map 0:a -acodec aac -preset fast -r 60 -vcodec libx264 out.mp4 -report -y`

As you can see, `-filter_complex` is used, the filtered video is mapped with `-map "[s0]"` and the audio is mapped with `-map 0:a`.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about the keyword `preset='fast'`, do you have a link to the documentation with this?

Comment: @kunambi You have to look in the documentation of FFmpeg CLI. Most options are not documented in ffmpeg-python documentation (ffmpeg-python is just a thin wrapper that executes FFmpeg CLI). preset='fast' applies the libx264 encoder. For getting the options execute `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264` from the shell. `preset` is also documented in [H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset).

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the composed ffmpeg command line, but I suspect `filter()` inserts `-filter_complex` and `-map` options which in turn excludes all other streams including audio. You need to add `-map 0:a` option to the command. I'm not familiar with `ffmpeg-python` but should be achievable by adding map keyword argument to the `output()` method. (pure speculation)

If you are OK with alternate package you can try my [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio), which tries to keep its API close to the FFmpeg.

To install

```
pip install ffmpegio-core
```

FFmpeg executables must be in the system path (or in one of the prescribed locations, see [documentation](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/install.html))

To run your command:

```py
import ffmpegio

ffmpeg.transcode(
    "input.webm",
    "out.mp4",
    vf="scale=force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:force_divisible_by=2",
    vcodec="libx264", r=60, preset='fast')
```